# SciTech's SVGAKit seems to be incomplete

Tags: ms-dos, programming, assembly

I'm trying to get into MS-DOS development for fun, and I'd like to use SciTech's SVGAKit library. The last version of it is still downloadable via the Internet Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20060118061752/http://www.scitechsoft.com/products/ent/free_titles.html). However it seems to be incomplete. SciTech seems to have split their build system up so that you'd need a set of support make files, that's OK I've found enough bits of that in other things to figure out how to build it myself. What I don't want to try to deal with is that one file seems to be missing: `svga.inc` for exporting definitions to call into the library from assembly, but it also defines structs for the library to use so I can't build the library without it.

I could learn TASM and re-create it based on the C headers... but I don't really want to.

If anyone out there has SciTech's MGL 3.0 library (SVGAKit was included in it) or a more complete archive of their FTP server from around 1996 I'd love hear about it!

The main reason I want to use SVGAKit is that it deals with a bunch of DPMI gunk to do with making sure things are mapped when calling into the VESA BIOS.

A suggestion for an alternate library that works with DJGPP would also be welcome.

Comment: There used to be a tool to convert C header files to INC files (MASM/TASM compatible). It used to be part of MASM and was called H2INC.EXE. Not sure it can help you? I think Borland may have had a similar tool. I wonder if the SVGA Kit make facilities may have used such a program to convert the SVGA.H file to SVGA.INC.

Comment: For the record, the Makefile support archive is `mkutil22.zip`, available from SimtelNet or [SMSW-6](http://annex.retroarchive.org/cdrom/smsw-vol6/PROG/MKUTIL22.ZIP).

Comment: @MichaelPetch As far as I can tell, they don't. I've seen multiple versions of them, I'm not sure which is the right version for building SVGAKit, but none of them seem to have rules to generate any includes... nor would the structure of them really work for doing it.

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm pretty sure that matches SVGAKit 5.2 the one that I have been trying to resurrect is 6.2, 5.2 doesn't seem like you're supposed to build it, it comes with binaries, but not for DJGPP. I'm not sure where in either package it says which version of the SciTech makefiles you're supposed to have.

Comment: @Spudd86 that’s certainly a possibility; I saw that `mkutil22.zip` includes support for DJGPP and jumped to the conclusion that it would be relevant for SVGAKit 6.2, since 5.2 doesn’t. But I didn’t try building 6.2 with `mkutil2.2.zip` (and in any case it doesn’t address your `svga.inc` problem, which is why I wrote that as a comment).

Comment: Back in the time before time, I used to use Allegro with DJGPP; it's a hodge-podge of random other functionality, especially in later versions, but it offers SVGA framebuffers with direct pointer access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete sources for SVGAKit seem to be part of MGL 4.05 as well. I'm not certain it's the same 6.2 version, but it's close.

The problem is that to get it you have to have Windows 3.1 and install MGL 4.05 and it's source code and then figure out how to separate SVGAKit from the rest.

MGL 4.05 is available from [here an ftp site](http://ftp.lanet.lv/ftp/mirror/x2ftp/msdos/programming/scitech/) and on [The Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20010717131700/http://www.scitechsoft.com/ftp/devel/) The files you need are:

- `mglb405.exe` The base install of MGL 4.05
- `mgls405.exe` Source code of MGL 4.05

You *must* successfully install the base before you can install the source. I had issues getting that working in DosBox so I used a real machine.

SVGA Kit seems to vanish entirely after MGL 5.0 came out. The version here may also include some changes to support DJGPP since MGL 4.05 does have DJGPP support.

I have pulled out I think enough stuff to get a stand alone DJGPP build of SVGAKit you can get it [here](https://github.com/Spudd86/svgakit) NOTE: building requires Borland Turbo Assembler since SciTech had not yet ported their assembly code to work with NASM's TASM mode or re-written for other assemblers.

Comment: The MGL sources appear to be here:  https://github.com/kendallb/scitech-mgl

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That is a MUCH MUCH MUCH newer MGL, it doesn't include the SVGAKit code I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry about that, hoped it could be helpful.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this tool for .h -> .inc conversion: https://www.japheth.de/h2incX.html